# Are the Liberation fonts 100% compatible with Microsoft Office?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, fonts, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

In LibreOffice in Linux, I can create a text document (.doc or .docx) which contains only Liberation fonts.

If I send this document to someone who opens it in Microsoft Word in Windows, and they don't have the Liberation fonts installed, can I be certain that my document will be displayed perfectly?

[This page](https://fedorahosted.org/liberation-fonts/) says that the Liberation font family "aims at metric compatibility" with its Monotype counterpart; but what does this mean in practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your document only consists of text without any formatting AND you embed the Fonts into the document, then it will most likely look the same in Microsoft Word. (But in this case, you might consider sending your document as plain text file)

But if you use more complex formatting, you can not be sure if it will look identical between different versions of Microsoft Word.

Be aware that newer versions of Word can open OpenDocument-Text files. So you might want to send it as odt.

The solution depends on your requirements:

- do you want the document to look as you designed it -> use PDF
- do you want feedback on your document from your receiver -> use PDF and let them use PDF comments/annotations
- should the receiver be able to edit your document -> use plain-text, or use as little formatting as possible
- do you want to have complex formatting AND editing from the receiver -> use the same program. (I admit, the solution is a little disappointing, but that's the current state right now).

If your only concern is fonts, then the result depends on how Word will replace a missing font. This is hard to predict, because people might have other fonts installed; they might even have a font called Liberation which is completely different.

This article shows how to control font replacement in Word:
http://wordribbon.tips.net/T012657_Finding_Words_Font_Substitutes.html

Comment: Unfortunately, a requirement is that the document has to be either .doc or .docx. It's for university.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that might help is to go to `Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice -> Fonts` and apply a replacement table.  For example, add an entry to replace "Arial" with "Liberation Sans".

The only way to be certain that the document will be displayed perfectly is to send them a PDF file using `File -> Export as PDF`.  However they will not be able to edit the document.

Comment: Adding an entry to replace "Arial" with "Liberation Sans" seems like what you do the other way around: having Office documents be compatible with LO. This question is about having LO Word documents be compatible with Office.

Comment: You can add the entry to replace Arial with Liberation Sans, and then proceed to use "Arial" in your document. It will be substituted with Liberation Sans on your screen for display purposes, but will stay as Arial for others.